# Basic for loop in Python 3

Tags: for-loop, python-3.x

I'm a beginner to Python and I'm having some trouble with this. I have to make a `for` loop out of this problem. Can anyone explain how I would go about this?

`nextNValues (startValue, increment, numberOfValues)`

This function creates a string of `numberOfValues` values, starting with `startValue` and
counting by increment. For example, `nextNValues (5, 4, 3)` would generate a string of
(not including the comments):

5 - the start value
9 - counting by 4, the increment
13 - stopping after 3 lines of output, the numberOfValues

Comment: You could use `range(startValue,startValue+(increment*numberofValues),increment)`

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy add that as an answer and I'll remove my answer :)

Comment: Do you want a string? Or do you want to print the numbers to the console? Or do you want a list of numbers?

Comment: I can't use a print statement inside the function. So I have to use a return statement and then create a "main" function where I would print the output. this is what I got so far:

Comment: def nextNValues (startValue, increment, numberOfValues):
    result = 0
    for i in range (numberOfValues):
        result = startValue + i * increment
    return increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(numberOfValues):
    print startValue + i * increment
```

I am not sure if that is exactly what you are looking for... but it is my suggestion based on the information you have posted.

Comment: this was a huge help! Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 3):

You could use `range(startValue,startValue+(increment*numberofValues),increment)`.

Comment: +1 also you can use xrange and produce a generator (where the sequence is generates as each next element is accessed instead of all at once like this (this is good if you want a LONG sequence)

Comment: there is no xrange in python3.range=xrange in python3. :)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easiest to write a for loop with an index like i and use that to add i*increment ti start value and save the resulting value to a list. Have the loop run numberOfValues times. If this is homework it would be better for you to write out the actual code for yourself